# else in the end of for and while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

who can say me:
What is the difference between writing code inside else or just after the loops?

```
for x in range(6):
    print('hello')
print('bye')
```

or

```
for x in range(6):
    print('hello')
else:
    print('bye')
```

Comment: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Comment: Read this "else" as "nobreak".

Comment: either `break` or `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`for/else` documentation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html):

> The else clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did not encounter a break statement.

This means that in your specific example there is no difference in using `else` or not.

Comment: Why did you answer this?

Comment: Do you mean that the difference is whether there is a break statement or not?
If there is a break command and the loop breaks, the other else commands will not be executed?

Comment: @T_F_E yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you're using conditional statement, Whereas in the first scenario after the loop completes, It automatically executes the next line.

Basically your post is an example of getting same result with alternative solutions.

Though your first solution can be considered as valid practice comparing with second one.

Although I would suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article before posting any questions on stack overflow.